# How to convert dates in a dataframe to a Date datatype?

Tags: r

I've imported one date value into R:

```
dtime <- read.csv("dtime.csv", header=TRUE)
```

It's output (7th Nov, 2013) is printed as:

```
> dtime
              Date
1 07-11-2013 23:06
```

and also its class is 'factor'.

```
> class(dtime$Date)
[1] "factor"
```

Now, I want to extract the time details (hours, minutes, seconds) from the data. So, I was trying to convert the dataframe's date value to Date type. But none of the following commands worked:

```
dtime <- as.Date(as.character(dtime),format="%d%m%Y")

unclass(as.POSIXct(dtime))

as.POSIXct(dtime$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

How do I achieve this in R???

Comment: You don't have seconds in this data. Either Way, if you want to extract hours and minutes, try `Res <- as.POSIXlt(dtime$Date,  format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M") ; Res$hour ; Res$min`

Comment: @David: Yeah. Thanks for noticing.. I was just trying to give details about what I'm trying to achieve, just in case in the future if I use these answers on a date value that has seconds as well.

Comment: @Hey David.. your suggestion worked.. Thank you so much..  And also can you please tell me why the commands I tried in the question didn't work?? What was stopping them from conversion??

Comment: You didnt specify the correct format in `as.Date`. You also added seconds in `as.POSIXct` (while they are not present)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempts didn't work because the format specified was wrong.

With base R there are two possible ways of solving this, with `as.POSIXlt`

```
Res <- as.POSIXlt(dtime$Date,  format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
Res$hour
Res$min
```

Also, for more options, see

```
attr(Res, "names")
## [1] "sec"    "min"    "hour"   "mday"   "mon"    "year"   "wday"   "yday"   "isdst"  "zone"   "gmtoff"
```

Or a bit less conveniently with `as.POSIXct`

```
Res2 <- as.POSIXct(dtime$Date,  format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
format(Res2, "%H") # returns a character vector
format(Res2, "%M") # returns a character vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute solution utilising `lubridate` :

```
dates <- c("07-11-2013 23:06", "08-10-2012 11:11")
dta <- data.frame(dates)
require(lubridate)
dta$properDate <- dmy_hm(dta$dates)
```

If needed, `lubridate` will enable you to conveniently [specify time zones or extract additional information](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html).

Comment: That seems like a very helpful information.. thank you so much for sharing.